# DevExpress Toggle Button - How To Check ON/OFF State? .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress

Simple enough question, and that's why its been bothering me. I have a toggle button from DevExpress that I wish to use, but I cant seem to understand the syntax for checking to see if it's toggled on or off. I've checked their official stite and developer forums, but cant seem to find an asnwer to the most simple question. I basically want to do this:

```
Private Sub ToggleBackgroundMusic_Toggled(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToggleBackgroundMusic.Toggled

If ToggleBackgroundMusic.toggle = True then 
  'is toggled on
else 
  'is toggled off
end if 

 End Sub
```

But I've tried everything I can think of. Using the togglebuttons **.properties** control doesn't contain anything I could use, at least from what I've noticed... Any help?

Comment: Could you please provide the class of the toggle button you used ?

Comment: @user2941651 Hi, it was under DX.14.1: Common Controls> ToggleSwitch in the toolbox, it's version 14.1.6.0. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: There was syntax mistake in my answer. I've corrected it and now it should be OK. I'd be grateful for your reply whether it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the `IsOn` property (the docs you should find **[here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsToggleSwitch_IsOntopic)**):

```
Private Sub ToggleBackgroundMusic_Toggled(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToggleBackgroundMusic.Toggled

  If ToggleBackgroundMusic.IsOn = True then 
     'is toggled on
  else 
     'is toggled off
  end if 

End Sub
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but `==` is not relevant for checking equality in Visual Basic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, == was not relevant. A single = worked. Thank you.